# Kali Linux update error

Tags: linux, apt-get

When I try to update my kali linux whit the command apt-get update I get 3 errors:

```
Err http://http.kali.org/wheezy/main amd64 Packages   404  Not Found

Err http://http.kali.org/wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages  404  Not Found

Err http://http.kali.org/wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages  404  Not Found
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Fix the source e.g. with `http://http.kali.org/dists/kali-current/`. If you want to keep the same site you can see what is available from `http://http.kali.org/dists/`

Answer (score 3):

Open you terminal and type those text in below

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that you clear the text file paste

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20141002-11:29]/ kali contrib main non-free
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20141002-11:29]/ kali contrib main non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib

## Security updates
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

After that you save the file and exit.

Then type in terminal

> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

If it fail then try two or three times. **Remember** don't use 3rd party repositories.

Answer (score -1):

After several trials, I found the answer here:
http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

It says to make a single entry in the sources.list file
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

Comment: Link-only answers are not often that helpful.  Please read the help center for guidance on how to write an answer which might have reference links contained within them.  Feel free to add all relevant information, somebody reading your answer, shouldn't even have to click on the links you provide ( they should exist only for citation purposes ).  *If they are not important enough to quote don't include them.*

Comment: May not have been a narrative, but it is the only correct answer here given the deprecated repo: http://security.kali.org/kali-security/README

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem , but this fixed it for me :-

### Add the following in your /etc/sources.list file and delete the previous contents.

```
deb http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Now check with `sudo apt-get update` . This had fixed it for me.

Comment: A previous answer suggested changing `/etc/sources.list` (well, actually, `/etc/apt/sources.list`). Why do you believe that this user will be better off with Italian mirrors?